# How to uncheck item checked by setItemChecked ()?

Tags: android, listview, multiple-select

I am using a ListView with `MULTIPLE_CHOICE` and to get the selected items back i am using `setItemChecked()` method.

It works fine as i am able to see the previously checked items.
The issue is that if i *uncheck* one of the *previously checked* items, and then get the list of checked items by `custList.getCheckItemIds()`
the array still has the Item that i unchecked.

Can anyone please tell me if that is supposed to happen or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to call setOnCheckedChangeListener and you have to manage the code inside this listener block.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              // Write and manage your code here.
        }
});
```

Comment: I am not using a custom layout so i am not sure how will i be able to get the CheckBox object. Here is the code snippet:


`custList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.custList);
   custList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
//Array Adapter to fill the list uses android layout for list with //multiple choice
adaptCust =  new ArrayAdapter<CDOCustomer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,customers );
  custList.setAdapter(adaptCust);
`

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to find out what items are checked at any given time, you can get a SparseBooleanArray from the ListView, and iterate over it with a for loop. For example:

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++){
    if (checked.get(i))
        //the item at index i is checked, do something
    else
        //the item is not checked, do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++){
    if (checked.get(i))
        //the item at index i is checked, do something
    else
        //the item is not checked, do something else
}
```

doens't work.

follow [Multiple Contact Picker List [getCheckedItemPositions()]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976691/multiple-contact-picker-list-getcheckeditempositions)

should be OK.

```
SparseBooleanArray selectedPositions = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

for (int i=0; i<selectedPositions.size(); i++) {
    if (selectedPositions.get(selectedPositions.keyAt(i)) == true) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```